# Removing duplicates from a Dojo FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo, duplicates, dijit.form

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a Dojo FilteringSelect without changing the contents of the attached itemFileReadStore data store. I can't seem to find any information on how this is done, if it is indeed possible.

I'm thinking I may have to extend the FilteringSelect Dijit and provide the functionality myself but I'm hoping to not have to.

The reason I'm trying to remove duplicates with the FilteringSelect and not the data store is because I'm using the same data store with three instances of the FitleringSelect, each displaying different values from each row of the store.

Answer (score 1):

If your store FilteringSelect searchAttr is the same as in your dataStore "identifier", you will see a unique set of values in the dropdown.

For example, if you change the identifier from myStore to "color", your dropdown will show only red, orange and yellow instead of having a duplicate yellow.

That is why, if you use this store definition in your FilteringSelect and set the searchAttr to "Fruit" you will see only two values; orange and apple

```
var myStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
                url: 'data.json'
            });
```

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" store="myStore" id="fsKeywords" searchAttr="name" onChange="filterGrid()"></div>
```

*data.json file:*

```
    

{
    identifier: "Fruit",
    label: "Name",
    items: [
         {
              "Fruit":"orange",
              "color":"red",
          "size":"small"
    },
         {
              "Fruit":"orange",
              "color":"orange",
          "size":"big"
    },
         {
              "Fruit":"orange",
              "color":"yellow",
          "size":"small"
    },
        {
              "Fruit":"apple",
              "color":"yellow",
          "size":"small"
    }
]}
```

I wonder if there is a way to change the store identifier programatically